# Modifying / Removing a text link makes button inactive

Tags: template-scripting

I'm trying to modify this piece of code in my template so that I can remove the text that says to "download a module" but when I do, it breaks the "quiz button" link / makes the button inactive. Anyone have any input on how I can resolve this issue? It seems like the two are connected somehow, but I need to modify just one of them, the download module link. TIA!

---

```
{embed="Includes/header"}


<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cycle.js"></script>
<script>
function gototop(){
$('body,html').scrollTop(0);

}

$(function(){
var bc = $('#buttonContainer'); 

var $container = $('#quiz_container').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
    speed:   300, 
    timeout: 0,
    after: function (curr, next, opts) {
$('.navidentifyb li').removeClass('active');
   $('.navidentifyb li').eq(opts.currSlide).addClass('active');
} 
}); 




i=0;
$container.children().each(function(i) { 
    // create input 
    var text = $(this).children('h3').text();
    $("<li><a>"+text+"</a></li>") 
        // append it to button container 
        .appendTo(bc) 
        // bind click handler 
        .click(function() { 
            // cycle to the corresponding slide 
            $container.cycle(i); 
            //return false; 
        }); 


z=0;
$('#quiz_container div').each(function(z){

            $(this).children('.btn').click(function() { 
            // cycle to the corresponding slide 

            $container.cycle(z); 

        });
  z++;
        }); 
});

});




</script>


{exp:channel:entries channel="CE_Courses" limit="1"}    
<div id="headerpromo"><img src="{course_header}" alt="About Putney" /></div>


    <!--    PAGE CONTAINER -->
    <div id="pagebody">


    {embed="Sidebars/education" id="205" }




    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div id="content">

    <h1>{title}</h1>
<p>Course information written by: <b>{presenter}</b></p>    


    {course_body}

<? $quizlink = "{quiz_link}"; ?>

{if course_type =="Video"}

<?
$mod = "{module_notes}";
?>
<script>

$(function(){
$('#quiz_container').append('<p><a href="<? echo $mod; ?>">Click here</a> to download notes from the module.</p>');
});
</script>
{/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
    <div id="quiz_container">





<? $i = 0; ?>

  {exp:channel:entries channel="course_chapters" sort="asc" orderby="chapter_number" related_categories_mode="yes"  limit="100" custom_fields="yes"  }
<div>    
<h3>{title}</h3>

    {chapter}

{if absolute_count == total_results}
<a class="btn" href="<? echo $quizlink; ?>" target="_blank" >Take the Quiz <i class="icon-caret-right"></i></a>
{if:else}
<a href="javascript:gototop();" class="btn" >Next <i class="icon-caret-right"></i></a>

{/if}


</div>
<? $i++; ?>



{/exp:channel:entries}

    </div
            </div>



    </div>
    <!--    /MAIN CONTENT -->


    </div>
    <!-- /PAGE CONTAINER -->


    {embed="Includes/footer"}


        <div id="promos">
            <a href="/howtobuy"><div class="promo">How to Buy</div></a>
            <a href="/vetsignup"><div class="promo">Veterinarian Sign Up</div></a>
            <a href="/whyputney"><div class="promo">Why Putney Generics</div></a>
        </div>




    </body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: Can you explain why you are using PHP in this template? I'm not sure it's related, though a double quote in the content of those variables would break your PHP, but, it doesn't appear you are doing any processing with the PHP and even have some that does nothing, e.g. the `$i` increment.

Comment: I'm not sure why the developer used PHP. Unfortunately, I've been tasked with making the updates and the original developer is no longer available. So I'm certainly open to trying other suggestions if you have other thoughts on how it could be set up.

Comment: What have you tried, exactly? Can you either change the text within the `<p>` tag being added, or remove the function that writes it entirely? If not - at worst, you could add an id to said `<p>` tag and then hide it with css - but that seems tacky. :)